# Whats the best way to implement hidden debug options?

Tags: java, android

I'm deploying an app in my company to keep track of production etc. Now I wonder how I should implement a hidden debug menu. In my C# programs I usually make a 2px by 2px hidden button in the bottom left corner of the main window, but this seems impractical for an android touch app. In case something goes wrong i need to have a way to open a menu that nobody, who doesnt know exactly how to open it, will ever find. I tried googling but all I found was how to hide/disable the dev settings in the android settings.

So what would be practical solutions to this problems without having to plug it into a PC or have to go to a separate app?

Comment: Do you have any kind of login?

Comment: Sort of. The workers just select their name from a list. But on this list there shouldn't be any visible admin accounts as there is no password required for login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a suggestion : listen to a multitouch pattern (only the sequence of added / removed touches, not the position).
It is easy to do in [Activity.dispatchTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))
without interfering with the UI, and difficult to trigger by chance.

A simple implementation (sorry it's in Kotlin, but it should be fairly easy to translate in Java) :

```
class DebuggableActivity : Activity() {

    // This pattern means :
    // 1, 2, 3, 4 : touch with 4 fingers (adding one at a time)
    // 3, 2 : removes 2 any touches (again one at a time)
    // 3, 2 : add, then remove one touch
    val pattern = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2)

    // current number of touches
    val pointers = mutableSetOf<Int>()

    // current position in pattern
    var patternIndex = 0

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (ev.actionMasked) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                // new gesture, reset
                pointers.clear()
                patternIndex = 0
                pointers.add(ev.getPointerId(ev.actionIndex))
                checkPattern()
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN -> {
                // new touch
                pointers.add(ev.getPointerId(ev.actionIndex))
                checkPattern()
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> {
                // touch released
                pointers.remove(ev.getPointerId(ev.actionIndex))
                checkPattern()
            }
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    }

    fun checkPattern() {
        if (pattern[patternIndex] == pointers.size) {
            // progressing

            patternIndex++

            if (patternIndex == pattern.size) {
                // triggered debug mode
                patternIndex = 0
                showDebugDialog()
            }
        } else {
            // failed, reset
            patternIndex = 0
        }
    }

    fun showDebugDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Debug mode")
        .setItems(arrayOf<String>("option 1", "option2", "option3"), { dialog, which ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on " + which)
        })
        .show()
    }

    ....

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the answer of @bwt, I have updated the implementation to have a true pattern based on the number of fingers.

```
 // ---- DEBUG ----

// The number in the pattern means the number of fingers touching on the current activity.
private val pattern = listOf(1, 2, 3, 2, 1)

// current position in pattern
private var patternIndex = 0

private var shouldReadPointerCount = true
private var pointerCount = 0

override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val action: Int = event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
        pointerCount = 0
        shouldReadPointerCount = true
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (shouldReadPointerCount) {
            pointerCount = event.pointerCount
            shouldReadPointerCount = false
        }
        if (event.pointerCount == pointerCount) {
            Log.i(TAG, pointerCount.toString())
            checkPattern(pointerCount)
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
}

private fun checkPattern(count: Int) {
    if (pattern[patternIndex] == count) {
        patternIndex++

        if (patternIndex == pattern.size) {
            patternIndex = 0
            showDebugDialog()
        }
    } else {
        patternIndex = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: after some screen element gets clicked N times you then open an input dialog and ask for a secret that leads to the hidden debug screen. You can create an "About" menu that directs to a not-so-usefull screen with the name and version of the App and program the "magical clicks" on some label or image on that screen.

Comment: Yeah that's what I came up with too, I just thought there would be a more "elegant" way. Since the app is also used to scan QR-Codes I think I just print out a debug qr code and when this code is scanned I open the debug menu.

Answer (score 0):

@bwt's example translated into Java:

```
// Variables required
// Change pattern to indicate the sequence of touches required to activate
// the secret action.
private int[] pattern = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2};
private HashSet pointers = new HashSet();
private int patternIndex = 0;

// We override dispatchTouchEvent and count the number of fingers down
// based on the values in pattern. See:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441348/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-hidden-debug-options
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch(ev.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // new gesture, reset
            pointers.clear();
            patternIndex = 0;
            pointers.add(Integer.valueOf(ev.getPointerId(ev.getActionIndex())));
            checkPattern();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            // new touch
            pointers.add(Integer.valueOf(ev.getPointerId(ev.getActionIndex())));
            checkPattern();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            // touch released
            pointers.remove(Integer.valueOf(ev.getPointerId(ev.getActionIndex())));
            checkPattern();
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

private void checkPattern() {
    if (pattern[patternIndex] == pointers.size()) {
        // progressing
        patternIndex++;
        if (patternIndex == pattern.length) {
            // triggered, show debug screen
            patternIndex = 0;
            showDebugScreen();
        }
    } else {
        // reset
        patternIndex = 0;
    }
}

private void showDebugScreen() {
    // Open your diagnostic screen here.
}
```

An interesting enhancement is to check the value of a text widget in showDebugScreen, and if a particular value isn't there, return. That helps to reduce the chance that a user will stumble on it accidentally by drumming on the phone.